# Deploying app to Heroku; Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error

Tags: java, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple app to Heroku. I'm deploying it as a .war through the eclipse Heroku add-on.

It displays fine at the start but when I try to run anything I get the following error:

Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

You can see it here http://irishdarttimes.herokuapp.com/. It's a simple app that just reads an xml file for times.

My understanding is that I should have to compile my app with a lower jdk. I have tried 1.6 and 1.4 but I keep running into the same issue. Can anyone help me out, I'm fairly new to all this.

Comment: heroku seems to default to Java 6 which obviously can't run code compiled for 7 but there seems to be a way to change that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app

Comment: One of your jar dependencies might be compiled with Java 7. Do you know the name of the class which can't be loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

major version numbers are as follows :

```
J2SE 8 = 52,
J2SE 7 = 51,
J2SE 6.0 = 50,
J2SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

(source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)

try compiling with a JDK 1.7

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, changing the java.runtime.version from 1.6 to 1.7 in system.properties resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, I thought I had been compiling for 1.4 but I wasn't. I've changed it now and it's up and running. I presume 1.6 would work too but for my case this is perfect